# how to set up debugger in visual studio code for dotnet core with angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to debug the c# api controller for my solution. I'm able to debug the angular through chrome debugger, but when setting a break point in VSCode inside the c# controller it never gets hit.

Here is what I have for debugger options.
Are there configurations that I need to add. If so, how do I find out what needs to be added?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install c# extension?

Comment: @Johar Zaman The C# extension is installed. Why was my question down voted?

Comment: I don't know brother

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't install c# extension in VS Code.

I was able to debug c# code in vs code by adding c# extension.

If you still find any issue, let me know.